# Get value from relationship key

Tags: php, laravel, search, filter, eloquent

I am developing a laravel application which has the following eloquent models:

- **App\Models\Dumpdb** - Here I store all files information;
- **App\Models\DumpDownloadHistory** - Here I keep all the client files download history;

This is **Dumpdb** table and model -

```
// Database table
Schema::create('dumpdbs', function(Blueprint $table){
  $table->bigIncreaments('id');
  $table->string('hw')->nullable();
  $table->string('hwtype')->nullable();
  $table->string('hwtype2')->nullable();
  $table->integer('kw')->nullable();
  $table->string('dataset')->nullable();
  $table->string('enginetype')->nullable();
  $table->string('euro')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});

// Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\DumpDownloadHistory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dumpdb extends Model
{
  public function DumpDownloadHistory(){
    return $this->hasMany(DumpDownloadHistory::class);
  }
}
```

***DumpDownloadHistory*** table and model -

```
// Table
Schema::create('dump_download_histories', function(Blueprint $table){
  $table->bigIncreaments('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('file_id');
  $table->string('dataset')->nullable();
  $table->integer('downloadCost')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();

  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
  $table->foreign('file_id')->references('id')->on('dumpdbs');
});

// Model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Dumpdb;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DumpDownloadHistory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'dataset', 'downloadCost', 'file_id'];

    protected $table = 'dump_download_histories';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function dumpDb(){
      return $this->belongs_to(Dumpdb::class, 'file_id');
    }
}
```

I need to make a search filter where the User can search a files which he has already 
bought. 
For example, this is all files from Dumpdb model: 
[image]

This is how I want to look like if a user has pressed on the checkbox "Has payed":
[image]

This is what I get: 
[image]

My controller:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
      $dumpDb = Dumpdb::query();
      // Search values
      $hw = Dumpdb::select('hw')->distinct()->orderBy('hw', 'asc')->get();
      $pld = Dumpdb::select('hwtype')->distinct()->get();
      $hwtype = Dumpdb::select('hwtype', 'hwtype2')->distinct()->get();
      $kw = Dumpdb::select('kw')->whereNotNull('kw')->distinct()->orderBy('kw', 'asc')->get();
      $engine = Dumpdb::select('enginetype')->distinct()->get();
      $euro = Dumpdb::select('euro')->where('euro', '!=', 'NULL')->distinct()->get();

      // Search filters
      if ($request->has('hw') && $request->input('hw') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('hw', '=', $request->input('hw'));
      }

      if ($request->has('pld') && $request->input('pld') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('hwtype', $request->input('pld'))
                  ->orWhere('hwtype2', $request->input('pld'));
        });
      }

      if ($request->has('kw') && $request->input('kw') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('kw', '=', $request->input('kw'));
      }

      if ($request->has('engine') && $request->input('engine') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('enginetype', '=', $request->input('engine'));
      }

      if ($request->has('euro') && $request->input('euro') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('euro', '=', $request->input('euro'));
      }

      if ($request->has('ds') && $request->input('ds') != '') {
        $dumpDb = $dumpDb->where('dataset', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('ds') .'%');
      }

       // THIS FILTER NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
      if ($request->input('hasPayed') == '1') {
        $downloadHistory = DumpDownloadHistory::query();
        $dumpDb = $downloadHistory->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('downloadCost', '!=', 'NULL');
      }

      $dumpDb = $dumpDb->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(30);
    return view('dumpDb.index', compact('hw', 'pld', 'kw', 'engine', 'euro', 'dumpDb',  'hwtype'));
```

Any help will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should include the relationship when fetching the DumpDb. Laravel provides multiple ways to automatically get this:

### [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author', 'publisher'])->get();
```

You should load the `DumpDownloadHistory` from the DumpDb query ( `$dumpDb->with('dumpDownloadHistory')` ). After you've done so you can change your filter to query the related DumpDownloadHistory by [constraining the eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
$dumpDb = dumpDb->with(['dumpDownloadHistory' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('downloadCost', '!=', 'NULL');
}]);
```

That will simply load the relations if the where query is true. However, you also wish to constrain the DumpDb's, so you can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

This will only load the model if it has a certain type of relation, so you can use it like this:

```
$dumpDb = $dumpDb->whereHas('dumpDownloadHistory', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('downloadCost', '!=', 'NULL');
});
```

#### Update

---

Edit your DumpDb model to use this relationship:

```
public function DumpDownloadHistory(){
    return $this->hasMany(DumpDownloadHistory::class, 'file_id');
}
```

Your final controller should look like this:

```
// THIS FILTER NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
if ($request->input('hasPayed') == '1') {
    $dumpDb = $dumpDb->whereHas('dumpDownloadHistory', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('downloadCost', '!=', 'NULL');
    });
}
```

Get rid of the `$downloadHistory = DumpDownloadHistory::query();`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I getting error: ```SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dump_download_histories.dumpdb_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `dump_download_histories` where `dump_download_histories`.`dumpdb_id` in (2821, 2822, 2823, 2824, 2825, 2826, 2827, 2828, 2829, 2830, 2831, 2832, 2833, 2834, 2835, 2836, 2837, 2838, 2839, 2840, 2841, 2842, 2843, 2844, 2845, 2846, 2847, 2848, 2849, 2850) and `user_id` = 688 and `downloadCost` != NULL)``` For some reason I getting errror on relationship.

Comment: Yes that's right, because you've only provided the relation it will automatically look for a dumpdb_id, but you're using a file_id if I'm right. So you should provide the 'foreign key' to the relationship. I've updated my answer to get you the right relationship definition.

Comment: Thanks very much! That works now! I was confused with relationship, how to connect in the other side, but now I get it.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck with your project.